# Sharing information between nodes in Beowulf Cluster

Tags: ldap, storage, cluster

I am setting up a beowulf cluster and I've been reading that it might be necessary to make the home directory of the cluster users shared between them (assuming this users are local to each machine). The other case is leave each user with its own home and the communication is up to the master node. Another idea that came up was to use an LDAP unique user logged on each machine in the cluster, that keeps the idea of the shared home between nodes (but is only one home of one user).

Which approach is better for this kind of cluster?

Edit: The cluster is running openmpi and it will support cuda and opencl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way. You definitely should use ldap for authentication of all your users except system users (root, daemon etc...). That way you get consistend uid's/gid's which is vital for the next step: NFS.

Either mount `/home` via NFS from a central host, or use automount to mount individual homedirs upon access/login.